# How to let plotly remove zero value bars?

Tags: r, plotly

I use `plotly` to make some bar charts. Sometimes there are zero value bars. Because I use plotly in an interactive flexdashbard I don't know in advance whether there are zero value bars or not. How can I let plotly remove those bars from the final plot?

This is een example of code I use:

```
    library(plotly)
        
    set.seed(123)
    variables <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4")
    df <- data.frame(number = sample(1:10,100,replace = TRUE),
     group1 = sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
     group2 = sample(1:6,100, replace = TRUE),
     variable = variables[sample(1:4, 100 ,replace = TRUE)],
     score = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(score=ifelse(variable == "var1", 0, score))

fig <- plot_ly(df,
               y = ~variable, x = ~score,
  type = 'bar',
  orientation = 'h',
  mode = 'markers',
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'aggregate',
      groups =  ~variable,
      aggregations = list(
        list(
          target = 'x', func = 'sum', enabled = T
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

fig
```

As you can see the var1 bar has value 0. How can I let plotly remove the var1 bar?

Comment: Would filtering be an option, i.e. dplyr::filter(df, score > 0)?

Comment: unfortenately not, because I use crosstalk filtering I need plotly itself decide whether to remove bars.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out myself.

The thing I need to do is add this piece of code in the transforms list:

```
list(
                type = 'filter',
                target = ~score,
                operation = '>',
                value = 0
            ),
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in python?